# Code compilation errors for 101 - no errors with Uno

Tags: compilation-errors

I asked [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/65312/unresolved-reference-to-public-function-from-library) before a few days ago about undefined references errors to custom library functions. By accident I found that the code compiled fine when the board target was set to an Uno, not the Intel Curie 101 that I was indending to use (and what is was set to when the errors appear) Can anyone explain why you would get undefined reference errors that are board specific?

Disclaimer - I haven't got access to the hardware I need to test at the moment so I don't know for certain that the code works on an Uno.

**Edit:**
I have tested the compilation for a few board targets as below

- Uno - no errors
- Mega / Mega 2560 - no errors
- Leonardo - no errors
- Due - no errors
- 101 - `undefined reference` as detailed in linked question

Additionally, moving the libaries into the sketch folder rather then having them in the Arduino libaries folder stops compilation errors. Is there a difference in how the 101 links to included files?

Comment: why did you create a new question instead of updating the original question with this new information?

Comment: I made a new question as in my mind this is a different issue to the previous question. The original post was more asking for code advice as that's what I believed the issue was - where as this is now more about the behaviour of Arduino in general. For someone who has the same problems that I have encountered about baord specific compilation errors then this would be a more helpful question would it not?

Comment: if the other question gets deleted, then this one becomes broken .... your question should stand on its own

Comment: it is unclear what your question actually is .... the Uno and the Curie use different microcontrollers, therefore the libraries are different

Comment: @jsotola: The OP's question is about *their own* library.

Comment: `error.h` is not a good name for a library. Some cores or compilers (the Curie one included) have an "error.h" file within them.